# Problems with httpget connection

Tags: android, http-get

i'm trying to send parameteris with GET to a script, but i'm receiving this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=http://www.myurl.com/~or/senddata.php?paramDevice={deviceInfo}&paramVersion={osversion}
```

This is my code:

```
String url = "http://www.myurl.com/~or/senddata.php?paramDevice={deviceInfo}&paramVersion={osversion}";
String encodedUrl = URLEncoder.encode(url,"UTF-8");
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(encodedUrl));
```

I see some other questions with this exception but all of them have very huge answers with classes and complicated methods, and i just want a minimalistic httpget conection that sends these two parameters to an script. I can't fit these answers with this code.

What am i doing wrong in my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode the parameter only, not the whole url :

```
String url = "http://www.myurl.com/~or/senddata.php?paramDevice="+URLEncoder.encode("{deviceInfo}")+"&paramVersion="+URLEncoder.encode("{osversion}");
    try {
         HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
         httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: i did it, and now i dont get the exception, but my php script is not receiving anything.... ¿why?

Comment: i think there is a problem with the URL ENCODE

Comment: Please open a new question for that. 
Do accept the answer ,if it solved your problem.
Thanks.

Comment: The server is returning response code - 200. I guess you need to send the a valid "deviceInfo" and "osversion". Or you need to check the server response.

Answer (score 0):

Please specify host in request. Do as following:

```
URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder();

builder.setHost("myhost.com").setPath("/views");

URI uri = builder.build();

HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
```